# JPA Bidirectional ManyToOne relation add a value in the foreign key column

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, annotations

I'm starting working with JPA, and I've created two entities like these:

```
@Entity
public class Company{
...
  @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "company")
  private List <Branch> branches;
}

@Entity
public class Branch{
...
  @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name="company_id")
  private Company company;
}
```

In the branch table on my db, jpa created the column "company_id" as a foreign key of Company ID (primary key of Company).

I've created some Company with Branches, and they're stored correctly on the database.

Now I'm asking myself how should I add just some Branches, and assigned them to one Company already stored on the db... 
Let's say I know the ID of the Company, how can I create a Branch having the "company_id" column with the given Company ID value? In the Branch entity I don't have a company_id column where I could put the company id value...

Is it clear my question? Sorry, I searched a bit, but i didnt' find nothing about it.

Answer (score 1):

Start by getting the Company instance which has the given company ID

```
Company company = em.get(Company.class, companyId); // or em.getReference(Company.class, companyId)
```

then create a branch with that company

```
Branch branch = new Branch(...);
branch.setCompany(company); // mandatory
company.getBranches().add(branch); // not mandatory, but advised to have a consistent graph
em.persist(branch);
```